# Using R: colnames() in for loop to change sequential datasets

Tags: r, for-loop

I have multiple data frames named y1 to y13 - one column each. They all have a column name that I would like to change to "Date.Code". I've tried the following in a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:13){
  colnames(get(paste("y", i, sep=""))) <- c("Date.Code")
}
```

That didn't work.

I also tried:

```
for(i in 1:13){
  assign(("Date.Code"), colnames(get(paste("y", i, sep=""))))
}
```

Also with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
E

Comment: are you changing all of the `colnames` or just a particular column?   On a side note, you have the arguments to `assign` turned arround (although, that still will not directly work)

Comment: Each data frame just has one column - and that's the column I would like to change. And thanks for the heads-up on the flip (I'm lacking sleep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here is that you cannot use `get` with an assignment operator directly
eg, `get(nm) <- value`  will not work.  You can use assign, as you're trying, but in a slightly different fashion.

assuming `cn` is the column number whose name you would like to change

```
for(i in 1:13){
   nm <- paste0("y", i)
   tmp <- get(nm)
   colnames(tmp)[cn] <- c("Date.Code")
   assign(nm, tmp)
}
```

### ---

That being said, a cleaner way of approaching this would be to collect all of your DF's into a single list, then you can easily use `lapply` to operate on them.  For Example:

```
# collect all of your data.frames into a single list. 
df.list <- lapply(seq(13), function(i) get(paste0("y", i)))

# now you can easily change column names. Note the `x` at the end of the function which serves
#    as a return of the value. It then gets assigned back to an object `df.list`
df.list  <- 
  lapply(df.list, function(x) {colnames(x)[cn] <- "Date.Code";   x})
```

Lastly, search these boards for `[r] data.table` and you will see many options for changing values by reference and setting attributes more directly.

Comment: Excellent! Less than 10 minutes and my problem is solved. You guys are great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here one liner solution:

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern='y[0-9]+')),
       function(x) setNames(x,"Date.Code")),.GlobalEnv)
```

Of course it is better to keep all your variable in the same list.